# Android 10 Impossible to delete multiple files (Scoped Storage)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I have been reading the android documentation and I can't find a solution to **delete multiple files without multiple dialogs** in Android 10 (API Level 29)
I found the following in the Android documentation:

- API Level < 29: Delete files without dialog, permission granted on app startup
- API Level > 29: Delete files by showing all files inside a dialog which the user has to confirm
- API level = 29: Delete files by showing a permission dialog for each file

This is very frustrating not only for me but for every user who has API level 29, because there are some use cases where up to 100+ files must be deleted.

Entry Point when wanting to delete media

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> {
    deleteMediaR(activity, uris)
}
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
    deleteMediaQ(activity, uris)
}
else -> {
    deleteMediaDefault(activity, uris)
}
```

**Above API Level 29**

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private fun deleteMediaR(activity: Activity, uris: ArrayList<String>) {
    val contentResolver = activity.contentResolver
    val collection: ArrayList<Uri> = ArrayList()
    collection.addAll(uris.map { uri -> Uri.parse(uri) })
    val pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, collection)
    activity.startIntentSenderForResult(
        pendingIntent.intentSender, 42, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
}
```

**API Level 29**

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun deleteMediaQ(activity: Activity, uris: ArrayList<String>) {
    try {
        deleteMediaDefault(activity, uris)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        if (exception is RecoverableSecurityException) {
            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = exception.userAction.actionIntent
            activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.intentSender,
                42, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
        }
    }
}
```

**Below API Level 29**

```
contentResolver.delete(uri, where, media))
```

This is a very frustrating problem only concerning Android 10. I'm assuming Google forgot to implement this feature into their API. However, I'm hoping there is a proper solution as this breaks the app when using Android 10.

Comment: Dont use the media store to delete files. Just use classic File class. You can do without one dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have to use media store because i want to read/delete images/videos. 
A good workaround seems to be using requestLegacyExternalStorage and preserveLegacyExternalStorage.
Seems like Google is aware of this problem and still supports legacy methods.

Comment: `I have to use media store because i want to read/delete images/videos. ` Nonsense. You can delete any file with java io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways, actually.

**1. Using mediastore :**

You can easily delete any media file using Mediastore delete API like this,

```
ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> deleteLauncher
            = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                        // Media files deleted successfully. Do your stuff.
                    }
                }
            });


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private void deleteAPI30(ArrayList<Media> mediaList, Context context) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        List<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
            uriList.add(mediaList.get(i).getAppendedIdUri());
        }
        Collections.addAll(uriList);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, uriList);
        IntentSenderRequest senderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent.getIntentSender())
                .setFillInIntent(null)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION, 0)
                .build();
        deleteLauncher.launch(senderRequest);
    }
```

P.S. You need to get the directory access permission using SAF directory chooser if things don't go off easy.

**2. Deleting using storage access framework (SAF) :**

```
public void deleteMediaSAF(ArrayList<Media> mediaList) {
        DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions().get(0).getUri());
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(mediaList.get(i).getPath());
            DocumentFile nextDocument = documentFile.findFile(file.getName());
            try {
                DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), nextDocument.getUri());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mediaList = loadMedia(DIR_NAME);
        adapter.setMediaList(mediaList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.deselectAll();
        if (mediaList.size() > 0) {
            hideEmptyView();
        } else {
            showEmptyView();
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

You can use these methods at for different APIs at the same time if possible. For an instance, using Mediastore API for Android 11 & above and using SAF API for Android 10.